# Change text on hover image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div id="container">
<ul>
<li><img src="#" /></li>
<li><img src="#" /></li>
</ul>
<h2>Some Text</h2>
</div>
```

What I want is simply to hover one of the images in the ul and thus change the text in the h2 field. It doesn't matter if it will be done with jQuery, javascript or css, but it should be as simple as possible.

And please explain your code with comments so I can understand it!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, jquery does this easily:

```
//mouseover any li tag and do the following
$("img").hover(function(){
     //get the html code in teh li
     var text = $(this).attr("src");
     //put that in any or all h2 tags
     $("h2").text(text);
});


$("img").mouseout(function(){
     $("h2").html("");        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `hover()` function in jQuery to detect when the user hovers over an `img`:

```
$('ul li img').hover(function() {
   $('h2').text('Some more text'); // set whatever text you want here
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZLtqQ/

Answer (score 0):

I think this solve your problem.

```
$("#container").find("img").each(function(){  //look for each img inside the #container div
  $(this).mouseover(function(){ // and when the mouse is over it
     $("h2").html($(this).attr("src")); // put the img source as h2 text
  })
})
```

Tip: put an id on the h2 so the script will put the value just in the h2 you want, enjoy :)